# ¿Por qué la función no reconoce el return que le pongo al bucle?

Tags: java

No consigo ver por qué mi programa no parece reconocer la variable *i* que le introduzco como return. La función debería devolver cero si por teclado le introduzco cero o un valor menor a ese o encontrar todos los posibles divisores del número introducido.

```
public class DGPt05e06 {
    
    public static int cantidadDivisores(int a){
        if (a<=0) return 0;
        if (a>0){
        for(int i = 1 ; i <=a ; i++){
            if(a%i==0) 
                return i;
}}
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a;
            int div;
            System.out.println("Introduce un valor");
            a=sc.nextInt();
            div= cantidadDivisores(a);
            System.out.println(a);
            
        } 
        }
```

Comment: Debuggeaste la función? qué te retorna?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon más contexto, tu método `main` y la forma en que estás llamando a `cantidadDivisores()`

Comment: Observa que la clase que nos muestras aquí se llama `DGPt05e06` mientras que el mensaje de error habla de una clase llamada `DGPt05`.

Comment: Osea, que tienes un error sobre que no encuentra o no puede cargar la main class, y tú preguntas que por qué no reconoce el return... El intérprete de java no sabrá nada acerca de tu return mientras no soluciones lo de la main class.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Esa es la cuestión. La main class no me presenta problemas. El codigo va correctamente, excepto que al invocar la función, me dice q no hay un return. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - missing return statement
 at com.mycompany.dgpt05.DGPt05e06.cantidadDivisores(DGPt05e06.java:1)
 at com.mycompany.dgpt05.DGPt05e06.main(DGPt05e06.java:26)
Command execution failed.

Comment: Pon el mensaje de error en la pregunta misma. Es ilegible en los comentarios.

Comment: Ese no es el error que pegaste antes. Y el código no puede ir correctamente, porque te está dando un error de compilación. Sobre esto te voy a dar una pista: la declaración de tu método `cantidadDivisores` dice que devuelve int, pero date cuenta de que en la definición del mismo no siempre devuelve algo (sólo devuelve si encuentra la condición). Deberías añadir al final un return con un valor por defecto, como ha hecho A. Cedano en su respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, observa que el  mensaje de error no coincide con el nombre de tu clase donde tienes el método `main`.

El mensaje de error dice:

> Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.dgpt05.DGPt05 Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.dgpt05.DGPt05

Pero tu clase se llama `DGPt05e06`. De modo que debes revisar cómo estás nombrado tu clase y el archivo `.java` que la contiene.

Por otra parte, cuando escribes un método que retorna algo, debes cubrir todas las ramas de dicho método, para que siempre retorne un valor del tipo esperado. En tu método actual hay ramas que no son cubiertas, no retornan nada. Además de eso, si lo que quieres es obtener el total de divisores que tiene el número dado, deberás ir contando dentro del bucle cuando la condición se cumpla.

Para no hacer tanto lío, es mejor hacer lo siguiente:

1. Declarar una variable inicializada a `0` que será el valor por defecto
2. Dentro del bucle, aumentar `1` a esa variable cada vez que la condición se cumpla.
3. Al final del método, retornar esa variable, que será `0` cuando nada se cumpla.

Así debería funcionar:

```
public static int cantidadDivisores(int a) 
{
    int finalValue=0;
    if (a>0)
    {
        for(int i = 1 ; i <=a ; i++)
        {
            if(a%i==0) 
            {
                finalValue++;
                System.out.printf("%d se divide entre %d%n",a,i);
            } 
        }
    }
    return finalValue;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
6 se divide entre 1
6 se divide entre 2
6 se divide entre 3
6 se divide entre 6
Cantidad de divisores: 4
```

Finalmente, tu código no tiene sentido, porque nunca imprimes el valor que te devuelve el método.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional, sin usar `Scanner`, porque no está disponible en ese contexto, por eso he puesto un valor cualquiera manualmente: [<kbd>`VER DEMO`</kbd>](https://rextester.com/FVNMIW66540).

He sacado por pantalla cada caso a modo de prueba, para que veas el sentido de lo explicado más arriba, esa salida por pantalla la puedes quitar posteriormente.

Comment: Eres un dios, muchísimas gracias.